# How do I make woocommerce error messages block the user from continuing?

Tags: error-handling, woocommerce

Approx 2 years ago, I wrote a custom plugin that checks order items in the cart for specific requirements.  If the requirements are not met, it displays an error and does not allow the customer to check out.  This code has been working well for approx 2 years.  Recently the code broke.  It must have been due to the recent WooCommerce upgrades, as we hadn't touched the code in ages.  I spent a while debugging it and this is what I found:

1. wc_add_notice doesn't do anything anymore.  When I changed it to wc_print_notice, it displays the error notice.
2. In the past, when I used wc_add_notice on the cart or checkout page, it would display the error message *and* not allow the user to continue to checkout.  Now that I am using wc_print_notice, it only displays the error message, but it *does* allow the user to continue.  I spent a long time working on this today and I can't figure out how to stop the user from continuing to check out.

Any suggestions..?

And, does anyone know where I can read documentation of the WooCommerce upgrade changes related to my issue?

Thanks!

PS:  If you want to see code samples, here are 2 articles which I found today, that display sample code doing exactly what my code does:
https://www.sitepoint.com/minimum-checkout-requirements-in-woocommerce/
https://gist.github.com/kloon/4545677

Comment: [2.6 intro](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/say-hello-to-woocommerce-2-6-zipping-zebra/). `wc_add_notice()` has not been deprecated and the gist works on my local site with WC2.6 Is the gist your actual code? Can you test your site with a default theme? It could be theme related.